# Code stops when a message box appears in IE using Access VBA

Tags: javascript, ms-access, vba

I am working on an automation using MS Access VBA and I am stucked at this problem as this messagebox stops the loop.

I have a couple of numbers then the code reads each of them, looks into IE, and closes the request. Unfortunately, upon closing each SR numbers, I get a message box *"Are you sure you want to finish package?"*

I tried `SendKeys {ENTER}` just to simulate the press of OK. Then read the next SR.

The problem lies there. The code stops when the message box appear. It is waiting for a user input either OK or CANCEL before it continues with the code.

How can I continue the code?

```
IE.Document.GetElementById("Finish").click 'code before the message box

'stops here.. it doesn't run the next codes..

WaitSeconds (2) 'this is a script that I use to wait for IE to load for 2sec
SendKeys {ENTER} 'to make it press enter and simulate the OK press on the msgbox, then repeat the loop.
```

If I manually click OK or press Enter. The code works perfectly. It loops through all data I loaded. But each of them has this msgbox, and I need to press the OK button again just to continue. Is there any workaround in this?

This is the Finish buttton -- after clicking this, msgbox appears.

```
<a tabindex="-1" title="Finish Package" class="level1 static" href="javascript: validatepackage('finish','vgpackage');">Finish</a>
```

This is the javascript or the backend code. I just typed it here, I am not able to copy it. Sorry for the lack of info.

```
    if (vgpackage && vgsubpackage && vgattachment) {
var responseMsg;
if (type == 'Finish') {
responseMsg = "are you sure you want to finish this package?";
} else if
```

Comment: Try `SendKeys "{~}", True`

Comment: Will that force the code to continue? As is stops after clicking the finish button because of the msgbox that appears in IE. But I will try tomorrow at the office. I can only try there. If you have any other options, pls feel free to list it, or maybe some links that can also help. Thanks